# Batch file to process the combining of 2 sets of pdf files together in a directory

Tags: pdftk

I am looking for a script that can do the following:

I have

- 500 pdf files with naming convention: SC####.pdf
- 500 pdf files with naming convention: AB####.pdf

I want a batch file to check if there is a #### match between the 2 sets of files.

- if there is, it will combine SCS####.pdf with AB####.pdf into a newly created file called ST####.pdf. (e.g. When you open file ST1099.pdf you see the contents of SC1099.pdf first, then AB1099.pdf contents second.)
- if not , it saves a new file as ST####. (e.g. SC0123.pdf has no matching file of AB0123.pdf, so the contents of SC0123.pdf are copied to ST0123.pdf.)

All 500 of the ST#### files are to be saved into a different directory and transferred via FTP to a server. The original SC####.pdf & AB####.pdf should not be deleted.

Ideally, I would like to execute automatically on the 1st of every month.

Comment: You would need a software that is capable of reading and writing PDF files, which is not as common as one would think. There might be some C++ or Java libraries out there that can do this, but trust me, it isn't a simple task.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible using a tool called [PDF Tool Kit](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/).  Download the tool and install, after that two pdf files can be joined using a command as follows:

```
pdftk A=SC1099.pdf AB1099.pdf cat output ST1099.pdf
```

This takes the files listed in A and concatenates them into output file ST1099.pdf.